# Ionic 4 : ngOnInit vs ionViewWillEnter

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-lifecycle-hooks

Which is better to use Angular Lifecycle Hook or Ionic Lifecycle hooks specially for initialization when creating a hybrid app using Ionic 4?

Angular lifecycle hook - ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
}
```

Ionic lifecycle hook - ionViewWillEnter

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.getData();
}
```

Comment: I'm working on an Ionic4 app that shows WordPress posts ionViewWillEnter() actually helped my app to fetch most recent posts each time i load the page as compared to ngOnInit() which kept loading old data from cache.

Answer (score 11):

**ionViewWillEnter** — Fired when entering a page (also if it’s come back from stack)

**ngOnInit** will not be triggered, if you come back to a page after putting it into a stack

i think better once **ionviewwillenter**

Answer (score 9):

The [Ionic 4 migration guide](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration/#lifecycle-events) puts it this way:

> With V4, we're now able to utilize the typical events provided by
>   Angular. But for certain cases, you might want to have access to the
>   events fired when a component has finished animating during it's route
>   change. In this case, the `ionViewWillEnter`, `ionViewDidEnter`,
>   `ionViewWillLeave`, and `ionViewDidLeave` have been ported over from V3.
>   Use these events to coordinate actions with Ionic's own animations
>   system.

So the bottom line is to **prefer Angular lifecycle hooks** like `ngOnInit` if possible. The only real exception is dealing with Ionics animation system like checking if a component has finished it's entering animation.

Comment: They must have later reversed this? I use "@ionic/angular": "^6.3.2". constructor and ngOnInit are called irregular. I use them to load initial data. I have to use ionViewWillEnter instead. Pretty annoying.

Answer (score 6):

In Ionic 4 Life cycle events are same as angular life cycle events.
Ionic 3 Life cycle events not worked here.

For Initialization you must use

```
ngOnInit()
```

If you want after view initialized,

Please change

```
ionviewwillenter
```

to

```
ngAfterViewInit()
```

This will works Fine.

Answer (score 0):

**ngOnInit**

Fired once during component initialization. This event can be used to initialize local members and make calls into services that only need to be done once.

**ionViewWillEnter**

Answer (score 0):

If you use

> ngOnInit()

then API data not load properly
and values not updated so i strongly recommend

> ionViewWillEnter()